# Looking to set an AssignedDate to datetime now on a purchase request form in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking to change a create date to assigned date with DateTime Now once a request has been assigned to the person working the purchase. I did see a few examples but it seems like they are using a specific time that it will be changed to. Unfortunately for me there will be no set time so it could be at 8am or 2pm just whenever the manager gets around to assigning the request. Hopefully I explained my goal well enough. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much information to go on here, but you should really be keeping 2 datetimes, a **Created** and an **Assigned**. And you can just make the DateTime for **Assigned** nullable and set it on save.

```
public class PurchaseRequest
{       
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt}")]
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt}")]
    public virtual DateTime? Assigned { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class PurchaseRequestService
{
    public Task Assign()
    {
        ...
        purchaseRequest.Assigned = DateTime.Now;
        ...

        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

*The three dots means more code added if needed in those spots*

Comment: Austin Thank you! I have a the create date already on the purchase work order just was not sure how to go about getting that assigned date. This is a great start. I appreciate it.